# MYSQL 1064(42000) Qustions

Tags: python, mysql, database

I have a problem with "1064(42000): You have an error in you SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '%s' at line.". Even though there are solutions already, I tried and it's still not working.

```
def add(self):
    con = mysql.connector.connect(
        host="localhost",
        user="root",
        database="ims"
        )
    cur = con.cursor()
    try:
        if self.var_name.get()=="":
            messagebox.showerror("Error", "Name Must be required", parent= self.root)
        else:
            name = self.var_name.get()
            search = cur.execute("SELECT * FROM dealer WHERE name = %s ")
            cur.execute(search, name)
            row= cur.fetchone()
            if row!=None:
                messagebox.showerror("Error", "This Dealer Name already assigned, try a different one", parent = self.root)
            else: 
                name = self.var_name.get()
                companyname = self.var_companyname.get()
                contact = self.var_contact.get()
                address1 = self.var_address1.get()
                address2 = self.var_address2.get()
                address3 = self.var_address3.get()
                add = ("INSERT INTO dealer (name, companyname, contact, address1, address2, address3) VALUES(%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)")
                cur.execute(add,(name, companyname, contact, address1, address2, address3))
                con.commit()
                messagebox.showinfo("Success","Dealer Addedd Successfully", parent=self.root)    
                self.show()
                self.clear()
                cur.close()
                con.close()
    except Exception as ex:
        messagebox.showerror("Error",f"Error due to : {str(ex)}", parent = self.root)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't call `cur.execute()` when setting `search`. The variable should be set to the SQL string, then you use that when calling `cur.execute()` on the next line.

You also have to put the parameters in a list or tuple.

```
            search = "SELECT * FROM dealer WHERE name = %s "
            cur.execute(search, (name, ))
```